# Open Link Clicked on Webview2 on edge browser new window

Tags: c#, webview2

I want to open new edge window on link click on HTML in webview2 popup.
Below code opens the url in same window.

```
private void webView21_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
 webView21.CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested += CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested;
}

private void CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested(object sender,CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs  e)
{
    e.NewWindow = (CoreWebView2)sender;
   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open the URI in the end user's default web browser instead of a new window in `WebView2` you can cancel the `CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested` event and send the URI to the browser:

```cs
private void webView21_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
 webView21.CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested += CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested;
}

private void CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested(object sender,CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs  e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    // No need to wait for the launcher to finish sending the URI to the browser
    // before we allow the WebView2 in our app to continue.
    _ = Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(args.Uri));
    // LaunchUriAsync is the WinRT API for launching a URI.
    // Another option not involving WinRT might be System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(args.Uri);
}
```

I have a [`CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested` handling sample code](https://github.com/david-risney/WebView2Samples/blob/9fb1cbc1b498e13764a3cd8bae5114f7876d3b06/SampleApps/webview2_sample_uwp/MainPage.xaml.cs#L45), that demonstrates different ways of handling `NewWindowRequested`.

Comment: Error I am getting
"Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0103 The name 'Windows' does not exist in the current context"

Seems I am missing some reference, can you please help.

Comment: As noted in the comment in the code LaunchUriAsync is the WinRT API for launching a URI. Another option not involving WinRT might be System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(args.Uri); It sounds like you don't have WinRT access so maybe try the other one